# How do I edit Liferay's HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, liferay, portlet

I was wondering if it's possible to edit Liferay Portal's HTML code, add a couple of `<br>` to have more space between portlets. Or even add some Javascript to it?
Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can use greasemonkey for Firefox, or you [install scripts to Chrome very easily](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/). Obviously this only affects your computer and doesn't change the _actual_ data on the server.

Comment: @ChristianVarga then there's no point in changing it if I can't change the actual HTML onthe server

Comment: Liferay is open source, you can change everything if you want.

Comment: To get more space between portlets, you do not want to edit the HTML but the CSS.

Comment: @Jocelyn I know it's open source, I guess my question is how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Theme answer has already been given - if you just want to change the appearance (e.g. linebreaks) this is the way to go instead of your original question to change HTML output.

If you literally need to change the HTML code - e.g. add something to or remove something from the page, you should read about [Hooks](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-ho-4), particularly those that can [override jsps](https://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4). This is exactly what they've been built for.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own **theme**, extending another theme (e.g. classic, _styled, etc.) and adding the 'diff' files, aka the ones you want to extend. In that case, you could extend a default css files, adding a rule like:

```
#content .portlet-layout .portlet-column-content {margin: 10px;}
```

Another quicker but less flexible approach is to use the

> 'Insert custom CSS that will be loaded after the theme.'

feature. This can be found at: Manage Pages > Look & Feel > CSS

Comment: See [Creating Liferay Themes](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7) for how to create a theme and [Anatomy of a Theme](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/anatomy-of-a-the-4) for its structure. You could then put your change in _diffs/css/custom.css.

For the second solution, you just insert your css rules in the text area under: 'Insert custom CSS that will be loaded after the theme.'